# Simple transfer erc20 from address to address on web page

Tags: erc-20

This is questions:

- [Using Solidity, how can I transfer ERC20 tokens from the current address to another?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/17322/using-solidity-how-can-i-transfer-erc20-tokens-from-the-current-address-to-anot)
- [Transferring an ERC20 token from one address to another](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/36526/transferring-an-erc20-token-from-one-address-to-another)
- [ERC20 token transfer to another address](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/124194/erc20-token-transfer-to-another-address)
- [Transfer contract to address or adress to address](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/49931/transfer-contract-to-address-or-adress-to-address)
- [Preventing Transfer from Specific Address in ERC20 Smart Contract](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/91975/preventing-transfer-from-specific-address-in-erc20-smart-contract)
- [Transfer from contract address to another address](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/69104/transfer-from-contract-address-to-another-address)
- [Using Solidity, how can I transfer ERC20 tokens from the current address to another?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/17322/using-solidity-how-can-i-transfer-erc20-tokens-from-the-current-address-to-anot)
- [Transfer from contract address to sender](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/108187/transfer-from-contract-address-to-sender)
- [Simple transfer from contract not working](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/46539/simple-transfer-from-contract-not-working)
- [Any erc20 token transfer simple code in ethers.js?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/80629/any-erc20-token-transfer-simple-code-in-ethers-js)
- [get Transfer events from 0x0 address for ERC20 token](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/71180/get-transfer-events-from-0x0-address-for-erc20-token)

ETC.....

No single answer show who to do it [not just here].
I just looking for most simple way to make transfer from one address to another on web page.

I need frontend part. Is it possible to do it?

I have clone of USDT on testnet.
I Use metamask also web3.

I understand "*The transferFrom method will only work if the owner (the _from address) has allowed the receiver ( _to address) to withdraw the funds, this is done by calling function approve(address _spender, uint256 _value) .*"

Comment: Please, can you add more details about your question? Or can you explain better the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will first need to establish connect your wallet to the webpage (and the library). I like to use [Ethers](https://github.com/ethers-io/ethers.js/) as the web3 client library.

```js
const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(window.ethereum, "any");
// Prompt user for account connections
await provider.send("eth_requestAccounts", []);
const signer = provider.getSigner();
console.log("Account:", await signer.getAddress());
```

After this, you need to create the interface for your contract. For this, you'll need two things, the *address* and the *ABI*

The address is the deployed address of the ERC20 token. Using the [USDC token address](https://etherscan.io/token/0xa0b86991c6218b36c1d19d4a2e9eb0ce3606eb48) here, and specifying the amount of decimals in the token.

```js
const CONTRACT_ADDRESS = "0xa0b86991c6218b36c1d19d4a2e9eb0ce3606eb48";
const DECIMALS = 6
```

The full ABI of a contract is created when building from Solidity. If you are lucky, you can [get it from Etherscan](https://www.turfemon.com/how-to-download-abi-from-etherscan).

Luckily, ERC20 contracts are standardized, so you can use a [general ERC20 abi](https://gist.github.com/veox/8800debbf56e24718f9f483e1e40c35c), or just provide the ABI of the single method you are using like this:

```js
const abi = ["function transfer(address to, uint amount)"];
```

Now you can initiate the contract and call the `Transfer` method.

```js
const erc20 = new ethers.Contract(CONTRACT_ADDRESS, abi, provider);

const transferToAddress = "0x..."
const amount = ethers.utils.parseUnits("1", DECIMALS);

await erc20.transfer(transferToAddress, amount)
```

[Here is a working codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/determined-visvesvaraya-8xs7ye?file=/src/index.js)

[image: codesandbox screenshot]

Comment: Sorry for crying, it works nice.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to transfer ERC20 from one wallet to another you can just use the "transfer" method, however the sender must have the ERC20 in the wallet. An example of this in javascript you can use:

```
let contract = new web3.eth.Contract("CONTRACT_ABI HERE", "ADRESSS HERE");
contract.methods
.transfer("USER RECEIVE ADDRESS", web3.utils.toWei("1000"))
.send({
  from: USER_SENDER,
  gas: 200000
}).on("receipt", async (response) => {
   console.log(response);
})
```

I hope it could have helped.

Comment: I will try it ! Looks nice

Answer (score 0):

you don't have to `approve` here. Why don't you just initiate a transaction with Web3.js in your frontend code.
`web3.eth.sendTransaction({from : "senderAddress", to : "ERC20TokenAddress", data :"abiEncodedTransferData"})`