# How to transfer custom ERC-20 token with Ethereum in one transaction

Tags: transactions, metamask, javascript, address.transfer, constant

I would like to send custom ERC-20 token with Ethereum in one transaction.
I know how to send both of them alone...
How to do it it one transaction?

[SEND CUSTOM ERC-20 TOKEN](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/125124/simple-transfer-erc20-from-address-to-address-on-web-page) (There USDC):

```
<script src="https://cdn.ethers.io/lib/ethers-5.6.umd.min.js" type="text/javascript">
</script>


<script>

const connectAndTransfer = async () => {
  const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(window.ethereum, "any");
  // Prompt user for account connections
  await provider.send("eth_requestAccounts", []);
  const signer = provider.getSigner();
  console.log("Account:", await signer.getAddress());

  const CONTRACT_ADDRESS = "0xa0b86991c6218b36c1d19d4a2e9eb0ce3606eb48";
  const DECIMALS = 6;

  const abi = ["function transfer(address to, uint amount)"];

  const erc20 = new ethers.Contract(CONTRACT_ADDRESS, abi, signer);

  const transferToAddress = "0x728713b41fcec5c071359ecf2802fa0b62bec5a8";

  const amount = ethers.utils.parseUnits("1", DECIMALS);
  await erc20.transfer(transferToAddress, amount);
};

connectAndTransfer();
</script>
```

And this code will send only Eth:

```
const ethereumButton = document.querySelector('.enableEthereumButton');
const sendEthButton = document.querySelector('.sendEthButton');

let accounts = [];

//Sending Ethereum to an address
sendEthButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
  ethereum
    .request({
      method: 'eth_sendTransaction',
      params: [
        {
          from: accounts[0],
          to: '0x2f318C334780961FB129D2a6c30D0763d9a5C970',
          value: '0x29a2241af62c0000',
          gasPrice: '0x09184e72a000',
          gas: '0x2710',
        },
      ],
    })
    .then((txHash) => console.log(txHash))
    .catch((error) => console.error);
});

ethereumButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
  getAccount();
});

async function getAccount() {
  accounts = await ethereum.request({ method: 'eth_requestAccounts' });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You may want to consider making your ERC20 also an ERC1363.
https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-1363

There is a function called transferAndCall that can send and execute in one transaction.

Comment: Thank you for link, could you send me example with USDC erc-20 please? Thank´s